# Microsoft Word Field Property issues

Tags: excel, ms-word

I am doing a merge from Excel 2007 to Word 2007.  I have a word document created with all the fields in place.  All fields are merging correctly except for one which is the social security numbers.  On my excel sheet (Input!) I have a field B5 that  auto converts to a social security number format (ex: 123-45-6789).  This is correct and this is how I want it to merge in the field on the Word document.

The issue is when I merge it will show on the letter as "123-45-67" (without quotation marks) It drops the last 2 digits.  I have went to field property in Words and confirmed the field type is "Number" and Max Length "15".  In the Number Format field I have ###-###-####  The results is the above.

Now when I leave everything the same and remove the format making it blank it returns 123456789 (without dashes)

I cannot figure out a way to convert this to a standard social security format with the dashes in place.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the Number Format field 3digits-3digits-4digits  (###-###-#### as you have in your question)? Not sure if that's part of the problem or just a typo in your question.

Comment: Is the social security number a text field in excel? If it is but you've told word it's a number this might be causing the problem.

Comment: If the data in excel is formatted as a custom number of some type so that it is stored as a number in excel perhaps you could format it as text using excel's TEXT() function? You probably wouldn't need to tell word anything about the format then.

Comment: Fraggle I ended up taking your last suggestion about changing the auto format feature in Excel from a SSN format to just a general text.  I also set General Text in Word and it worked fine.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a MERGEFIELD field in Word, with a different formatting switch (they do not use the same syntax as the Excel formatting patterns). If you Alt-F9 to reveal the field codes, it needs to look like this:

```
{ MERGEFIELD thefieldname \#"000-000-0000" }
```

or if absolutely necessary,

```
{ MERGEFIELD thefieldname \#"000'-'000'-'0000" }
```

You can enter such a field manually by using ctrl-F9 (cmd-F9 or fn-cmd-F9 on Mac) to insert the special field code braces {  }. Everything else is ordinary text.